# How to get current resource name

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am using MultiResourceItemReader in order to read and eventually write a list of CSV files to the database.

```
@StepScope
@Bean
public MultiResourceItemReader<DailyExport> multiResourceItemReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[listNotLoadedFilesPath]}") List<String> notLoadedFilesPath) {
    logger.info("** start multiResourceItemReader **");         
    
    // cast List of not loaded files to array of resources
    List <Resource>tmpList = new ArrayList<Resource>();
    notLoadedFilesPath.stream().forEach(fullPath -> {   
          Resource resource =  new FileSystemResource(fullPath);
          tmpList.add(resource);
      });
    Resource [] resourceArr = tmpList.toArray(new Resource[tmpList.size()]);
    
    MultiResourceItemReader<DailyExport> multiResourceItemReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
    multiResourceItemReader.setName("dailyExportMultiReader");
    multiResourceItemReader.setDelegate(reader(dailyExportMapper()));
    multiResourceItemReader.setResources(resourceArr);
    return multiResourceItemReader;
}

@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<DailyExport> reader(FieldSetMapper<DailyExport> testClassRowMapper) {
    logger.info("** start reader **");

    // Create reader instance
    FlatFileItemReader<DailyExport> reader = new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<DailyExport>()
            .name("dailyExportReader")
            .linesToSkip(1).fieldSetMapper(testClassRowMapper)
            .delimited().delimiter("|").names(dailyExportMetadata)
            .build();
    return reader;
}
```

Everything is working well but I also need to store the current file\resource name.

I found this API [getCurrentResource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/MultiResourceItemReader.html#getCurrentResource--) but I couldn't figure how to use it. Is there a way to get the current resource during the process stage?

```
public class DailyExportItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<DailyExport, DailyExport>{

@Autowired
public MultiResourceItemReader<DailyExport> multiResourceItemReader;
@Override
public DailyExport process(DailyExport item) throws Exception {
  // multiResourceItemReader.getCurrent ??
    
       
    return item;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ResourceAware](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/ResourceAware.html) is what you need, it allows you set the original resource on the item so you can get access to it in the processor (or anywhere else where the item is in scope):

```
class DailyExport implement ResourceAware {

   private Resource resource;
   // getter/setter for resource
}
```

then in the processor:

```
public class DailyExportItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<DailyExport, DailyExport>{

   @Override
   public DailyExport process(DailyExport item) throws Exception {
      Resource currentResource = item.getResource();
      // do something with the item/resource
      return item;
   }
}
```